# What is the fastest known algorithm for matrix multiplication as of (2017/11)?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, matrices

Recently I have learned about both the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) and the [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) (independently), according to the material I've used the latter is the "*asymptotically fastest known matrix multiplication algorithm until 2010*". As It can multiply two ( n * n) matrices in 0(n^2.375477)  time.

As of now (2017/11) I wish to know, is there another algorithm for matrix manipulation that was discovered since then (2010)?

I kind of knew in the CS field (I know I should probably do further research myself).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: I'd love to know what is the asymptotically fastest algorithm actually implemented. Strassen's algorithm is easy to implement and might be worthwhile even for n = 100 or 200. Is there anything _simple_ that beats Strassen, like a method to multiply 3x3 matrices with 21 or 20 products?

Comment: I found http://cs.stanford.edu/people/boyko/pubs/MatrixMult_SURJ_2004.pdf which claims that Strassen's algorithm is faster than the naive algorithm for around n ≥ 60,000. It seems they performed Strassen's algorithm recursively down to very small sizes, which is _not_ clever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the Wikipedia article you link to, it already describes improvements to the algorithms: "In 2010, Andrew Stothers gave an improvement..." and "In 2011, Virginia Williams ..." and "In 2014, François Le Gall  ...".  The latter is the best currently known algorithm.

To make this answer useful in the future: to verify whether this is still true or whether there is some further improvement, go enter those paper citations into Google Scholar and look at the papers that cite them.  If there were any improvements, the improvement would be published and would cite those papers.

Comment: `the improvement would be published` or [withheld by the alphabet-soup heroes](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/graduation/honorary-degrees/hondeg08/cocks.html) to spy out everyone and everything.